# Am I correctly adding styles to plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Today I noticed that two plugins (Opening Hours and Contact Form 7) had style conflicts. To fix the problem I decided to make it so that the stylesheet and js for Opening Hours would only be present on the admin pages. After some research this is what I came up with. It seems to works but is it okay? Thanks!

```
<?
/**
*   Register Styles
*/
function op_register_styles_backend() {
wp_enqueue_style('jQuery-ui-timepicker', op_baseurl() . '/js/jQuery.ui.timepicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.css', false, false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('jQuery-ui-style', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', false, false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('opening-hours-backend', apply_filters( 'op_backend_stylesheet', op_baseurl() . '/css/backend.css' ), false, false, 'all');

wp_register_script('jQuery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', false, null, false);
wp_register_script('jQuery-ui-timepicker', op_baseurl() . '/js/jQuery.ui.timepicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.js', false, null, false);
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery-ui');
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery-ui-timepicker');
}

function op_register_styles_frontend() {
wp_register_style('opening-hours-frontend', apply_filters( 'op_frontend_stylesheet', op_baseurl().'/css/frontend.css' ), false, false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'opening-hours-frontend' );

if (file_exists( op_assets_path().'/custom_style.css' )) :
    wp_register_style( 'opening-hours-user-stylesheet', op_assets_path().'/custom_style.css', false, false, all );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'opening-hours-user-stylesheet' );
endif;
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'op_register_styles_frontend');

/**
 *  Create Opening Hours Instance
 */
$wp_opening_hours   = new OpeningHours;

/**
*   Register Backend Options Pages
*/
 function op_register_options_pages() {
  // Top level menu item
$opening_hours = add_menu_page(
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_opening_hours', __('Opening Hours', op_textdomain()) ),
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_opening_hours', __('Opening Hours', op_textdomain()) ),
    apply_filters( 'op_min_user_capability', 'manage_options' ),
    'opening-hours',
    'op_setup_page'
);
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $opening_hours, 'op_register_styles_backend' );

// Holidays Page
$holidays = add_submenu_page(
    'opening-hours',
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_holidays', op__('Holidays') ),
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_holidays', op__('Holidays') ),
    apply_filters( 'op_min_user_capability', 'manage_options' ),
    'opening-hours-holidays',
    'op_holidays_page'
);
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $holidays, 'op_register_styles_backend' );

// Special Openings Page
$special_openings = add_submenu_page(
    'opening-hours',
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_special_openings', op__('Special Openings') ),
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_special_openings', op__('Special Openings') ),
    apply_filters( 'op_min_user_capability', 'manage_options' ),
    'opening-hours-special-openings',
    'op_special_openings_page'
);
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $special_openings, 'op_register_styles_backend' );

// Settings Page
$settings = add_submenu_page (
    'opening-hours',
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_settings', op__('Settings') ),
    apply_filters( 'op_menu_title_settings', op__('Settings') ),
    apply_filters( 'op_min_user_capability', 'manage_options' ),
    'opening-hours-settings',
    'op_settings_page'
);
   add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $settings, 'op_register_styles_backend' );
}

function op_setup_page() {
global $wp_opening_hours;
// include template
require_once    op_basepath() . '/templates/setup-page.php';
}

function op_holidays_page() {
global $wp_opening_hours;
// include template
require_once    op_basepath() . '/templates/holidays-page.php';
}

function op_special_openings_page() {
global $wp_opening_hours;
// include template
require_once    op_basepath() . '/templates/special-openings-page.php';
}

function op_settings_page() {
global $wp_opening_hours;
// include template
require_once    op_basepath() . '/templates/settings-page.php';
}

function op_admin_styles() {
/*
* Call backend styles ONLY if on an admin page.
*/
add_action('admin_init', 'op_register_styles_backend');
}

function manage_options() {
    /* Output admin pages. */
}

add_action ('admin_menu', 'op_register_options_pages');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, This is the correct way.

Many of us use styles to alter the look of our website, and scripts to enhance functionality. It is important to note however, that the way you add these scripts to WordPress is just as important as the content of these files. Instead of plopping them into the header or footer file we need to use WordPress enqueue functionality.

Take a look at the WordPress Codex for a list of included scripts OR direct to point Function Reference/[wp enqueue style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.